# Help with a proof involving connected spaces and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I wasn't sure the best way to word this in the title description so sorry if it's a bit vague. I'm struggling with the following homework problem.

> Let $X$ be connected, and assume a homeomorphism $A : X \to X$ exists such that $A\circ A(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that, for every continuous function $f: X \to \Bbb R$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = f(A(x))$.

My idea at a solution is to define a function $g(x) = f(x) - f(A(x))$ and show that it takes on both positive and negative values and then from there use the intermediate value theorem. Does this sound like a reasonable approach to the problem? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a reasonable approach. HINT: If $g(x)\ne 0$, consider $g\big(A(x)\big)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now.

Comment: @user316319: You’re welcome!